# Postgresql Auto backup using powershell and task scheduler

Tags: postgresql, powershell, automation, backup

I am running attached script to backup postgresql database by using task scheduler. Script is executed successfully but backup is not happening. Same script i have run on powershell and it's working fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpWT.jpg)

---

I want to schedule daily backup on windows server. Please help me or suggest any alternative to automate the backup.
Regards
Sadam

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, it will create a backup file with a name consisting of a timestamp:

First, create a `backup.bat` file and just run it (set your credentials and database name):

```
echo off
echo 'Generate backup file name'

set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)
set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%

set BACKUP_FILE=%CUR_YYYY%-%CUR_MM%-%CUR_DD%_%CUR_HH%-%CUR_NN%-%CUR_SS%.custom.backup

echo 'Backup path: %BACKUP_FILE%'
echo 'Creating a backup ...'

set PGPASSWORD=strongpas
pg_dump.exe --username="postgres" -d AdventureWorks --format=custom -f "%BACKUP_FILE%"

echo 'Backup successfully created: %BACKUP_FILE%'
```

As a result, you should see such a picture, and a file with the extension .custom.backup should appear in the directory

[image]

If you get an error that the executable file "pg_dump.exe" was not found, then specify the full path to this file, something like "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe", or add a directory with binaries PostgreSQL to environment variables (more details [here](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/setting-windows-path-for-postgres-tools))

-

To schedule regular execution, you can use the windows task scheduler

1. Press win + r and enter taskschd.msc
2. Select Create Basic Task
   [image]
3. Then follow the steps of the wizard, specify the schedule, and in the "Action" section, specify "Start a program" and then the path to the `backup.bat` file
   [image]

To check that everything is correct, find the task in the list and select Run

You can read more about Postgresql backups on Windows [here](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-backup-and-restore-postgresql-database)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Backup of particular database is working fine with the script i have attached but I am trying to take full backup of postgres. When taking backup from powershell it's working but when taking from task scheduler it's not working and showing 0 kb file.

Comment: Try to update your script:
1. Specify the full path to pg_dump. 
2. Specify the full path to the backup file.
2. Make sure that the SYSTEM user has write permissions to the directory where the backup is located.
3. Check the Run with highest priveleges flag in the task settings.
4. If you need a backup of a DBMS, not a specific DB, use pg_dumpall